# orderBy a grouped collection in linq.js

Tags: linq.js

Thats the code which does not work:

```
var grouping = Enumerable.from(periods)
                    .select(function(p){return new PeriodViewModel(p)})
                    .groupBy("$.periodNumber")
                    .orderBy("$.date")
                    .toArray();
```

the periodviewmodels are grouped by periodNumber and the date should be ordered ascending by the date, but that does not happen and I guess its because the selector in orderBy should somehow refer to the grouping result...

I have no clue. Thats test data so you can try it for yourself:

```
{
    "periods": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "content": "this is not a test",
            "date": 1,
            "periodNumber": 1,
            "documents": [
                {
                    "name": "Homework.doc"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Todo.xls"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "content": "this might be a test",
            "date": 2,
            "periodNumber": 1,
            "documents": [
                {
                    "name": "Homework.doc"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Todo.xls"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "content": "This is a clause",
            "date": 3,
            "periodNumber": 1,
            "documents": [
                {
                    "name": "Homework.doc"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Todo.xls"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "content": "and not sth to share for all",
            "date": 5,
            "periodNumber": 2,
            "documents": [
                {
                    "name": "Homework.doc"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Todo.xls"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "content": "hello kitty???",
            "date": 2,
            "periodNumber": 3,
            "documents": [
                {
                    "name": "Homework.doc"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Todo.xls"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "content": "Flynnie winnie",
            "date": 1,
            "periodNumber": 3,
            "documents": [
                {
                    "name": "Homework.doc"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Todo.xls"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "content": "what do yo say about chol and ra?",
            "date": 1,
            "periodNumber": 4,
            "documents": [
                {
                    "name": "Homework.doc"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Todo.xls"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the items before you group them. The `date` is not accessible from the group as you have it.

```js
var query = Enumerable.from(periods)
    .select(function (p){ return new PeriodViewModel(p); })
    .orderBy("$.date")
    .groupBy("$.periodNumber")
    .toArray();
```

Comment: haha and I also thought about that but then I thought that the order is not preserved by the groupBy maybe... should have tried that!

Comment: I don't know if this is in any specification or not but all linq implementations I've used preserves the order when grouping. Probably because it's easier to keep that order. Items are thrown into a group as they are processed, usually as a list/array. It would be senseless to use a collection that doesn't preserve order.

Comment: Turns out it is specified: [Enumerable.GroupBy()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534501%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#remarksToggle). "The `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` objects are yielded in an order based on the order of the elements in source that produced the first key of each `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>`. Elements in a grouping are yielded in the order they appear in source." In other words, the groups and the items in the groups are ordered as they are processed from the source collection.